# Which is the better way to check undefined in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I had been checking for `undefined` values myself like:

```
if(variable !== 'undefined')
```

then I came across the following code:

```
if(typeof variable1 !== 'undefined' || typeof variable2 !== 'undefined')
```

I followed the same convention knowing it's safer when variable goes undeclared. While in my code reviews, it was pointed I could simple write:

```
if(variable1 || variable2)
```

Which of these is the most standard way to check `undefined`?

Comment: Always go for approach 2

Comment: Are you talking about _undeclared_ variables or the value `undefined`? Because these approaches aren't interchangeable if you're asking about the former

Comment: never pass undefined variables to your functions by using functional programming versus procedural programming.

Comment: `if(variable !== 'undefined')` will *never* work, because `'undefined'` the string is not the same as the primitive value `undefined`. `if(variable1)` works if the variable, if defined, will always be truthy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various use case as following

1. `if (variable)` is standard way to check truthiness of any variable in javascript. You can examples of what values will be truthy on [Truthy | MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy). Also, [Falsy | MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)
2. The cases where you explicitly would check for undefined is when a variable has been declared but not assigned value or explicitly assigned `undefined`.
   In that case use `if (variable !== undefined)`.
3. If you are receiving response from an API which might consist of stringified value of `undefined`, which you are sure of, then only do the check `if (variable !== 'undefined')`